# How to Plot YCBCR color space image with matplotlib?

Tags: image, tensorflow, matplotlib, tensorflow2.0, color-space

This is my code it shows all color spaces except YCBCR ,,

Notation:ConvertLayer converts color space of image

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(16):
      plt.subplot(5, 5, i + 1)
      color_space = COLOR_SPACES[i%5]
      image = tf.expand_dims(images[i//5] ,axis=0)
      image = augmentation(NormalLayer(color_space)(tf.cast(image,tf.float32)))
      if color_space=="YCBCR":
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
      image = ConvertLayer(color_space)(image)
      #image = tf.cast(image * 255.0, tf.uint8)
      lbl = "{}({})".format(class_names[labels[i//4].numpy().argmax()] , color_space )
      plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(image))
      plt.title(lbl)
      plt.axis("off")
    break
```

[image]

I need to visualize it just in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code I was able to visualize the image in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=plt.imread("/content/car.jpeg")
y=rgb2ycbcr(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
rows = 1
columns = 2

fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, 1)
plt.imshow(x)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("RGB")

fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, 2)
plt.imshow(y)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("YCBCR")

def rgb2ycbcr(im):
    xform = np.array([[.299, .587, .114], [-.1687, -.3313, .5], [.5, -.4187, -.0813]])
    ycbcr = im.dot(xform.T)
    ycbcr[:,:,[1,2]] += 128
    return np.uint8(ycbcr)
```

Output:

[image]